# What __typename should be in Apollo Link State?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client

In the Todo example given in Apollo Link State docs it has a `__typename` property as follows -

```
const newTodo = {
        id: nextTodo++,
        text,
        completed: false,
        __typename: "TodoItem"
      };
```

Here it is `TodoItem`  but from where does it come from?

Can it be anything or is it something specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question

It can be anything

So in that case `TodoItem` as it was just a single `Todo`

Generally it will be the type specified in `resolvers`

So for `type Todo` the `__typename` will be `Todo`